# Best practice for implementing a blog page / section in wp_menu_nav()

Tags: theme-development, themes, wp-query, blog-page

I currently have a theme I am developing and had a thought on best practice. I am using `wp_menu_nav()` for my menus and they are linking to 4 or 5 pages respectively.  I would like to add a page / to this menu but do not want to add a specific template to list the blog posts, in addition I do not want the user going to edit a page called blog with no content in it.

What is the best way to implement a page with all blog posts to the current `wp_menu_nav()`.  This seems simple to me in theory but I want to make sure I am using best practice for this.

Open to hearing how you would go about this.

Thanks in advance,

JN

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out a solution to this issue even though it was not exactly what i was looking for.  In Settings -> Reading there is an option to set the posts page to a specific page.

What I did was.

1. Create a new page with my base page template.
2. Add this page to my main menu in the admin (Appearance -> Menus)
3. Configure this page to be my posts page (Settings -> Reading)

Comment: Nailed it! Nicely done, finding the answer to your own question. :)

Comment: Haha. Thanks Chip!  Sometimes that is the best way and you learn a bunch more along the process :)

Answer (score 0):

Blog posts are not pages, they are posts. The default 'post' loop is usually considered the "blog" and I consider it the best practice to keep it that way. Any other post "types" or loops should be based on a CPT or category/tag/taxonomy/widget/query/whatever.

The alternative solution that is sometimes used is to create a category called "blog".

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I maybe did not ask my question correcly or it was unclear. What I ended up needing to do is built into WP 3.  In the general settings page you can set a page to be your loop page and display all posts.  All i need to do was to configure the settings in the admin panel and voila!